# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-x}{1-x^5}\, d x $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, special-functions, beta-function

I want to compute the integral,
$$ \mathcal{I} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-x}{1-x^5}\, d x $$
And my attempt was like this, 
$$
\begin{align*}
 \mathcal{I} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-x}{1-x^5}\, d x \\
&= \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+x}{1+x^5}\, d x}_{\mathbf{I_1}} + \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-x}{1-x^5}\, d x}_{\mathbf{I_2}} \\
\end{align*} 
$$

I solved $\mathbf{I}_1 $ using Beta Function 
$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{I}_1 &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1+x}{1+x^5}\, d x \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \int_0^\infty \frac{1 + t^{1/5}}{(1 + t)} \, t^{-4/5} \, d t && \text{($ x^5 \rightarrow t $)} \\
&= \frac{1}{5} \left( \int_0^\infty \frac{t^{-3/5}}{(1 + t)} \, d t + \int_0^\infty \frac{ t^{-4/5}}{(1 + t)} \, d t \right)
\end{align*}
$$
We know that ,
$$ \beta{(m, n)} = \int_0^\infty \frac{ x^{n-1}}{(1 + x)^{m+n}} \, d x $$
$$ \beta{(m, n)} = \frac{\Gamma{(m)}\,\Gamma{(n)}}{\Gamma{(m+n)}} $$

And
$$ \Gamma{(x)}\,\Gamma{(1-x)} = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)} $$
So, 
$$ 
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{I}_1 &= \frac{1}{5} \left(\beta{(1/5, 4/5)} + \beta{(2/5, 3/5)} \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{5} \left( \frac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{5} \right)} + \frac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{5} \right)} \right)
\end{align*}
$$,

But I have no idea how to solve 
$$ \mathbf{I}_2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-x}{1-x^5}\, d x $$

I tried some substitution like $ x^5 = \sin^2(\theta) $ But didn't work. 
Would you please help me ? 
Thank you !

Comment: A brute-force approach would be to factorise over the fifth roots of unity and use partial fractions.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire yeah that's the option but my friend said to me that this can be solved using counter integration. And I've not studied that yet so I want to do it using real methods.

Comment: The complex analysis approach would be to integrate along $-R$ to $R$ and then in the half circle above the real line. The half circle part goes to $0$ and $R\to\infty,$ and the integral is exactly $2\pi$ times the residues at the two poles in the upper half plane.

Comment: @Luckychouhan *contour* integration